# $f$ satisfies $y''+by=0 \implies f$ is of class $C^{\infty}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the solutions are a linear polynomial (if $b=0$), a linear combination of exponencials ($b<0$) or linear combinations of sine and cosine ($b>0$).
However, supposing I didn't know this yet, would it be possible to conclude that $f$ has derivatives of all orders supposing that it satisfies the ODE?

Comment: if y satisfy $y''=-b y$ and y is in $C^n$ then $y \in C^{(n+2)}$ and iterate same thing. The key argument is y is "two scores" more smoother than '$y$' itself

Answer (score 9):

Hint: $f^{(n)}$ can be expressed in terms of $f^{(n-2)}$.  If that is differentiable, ...

Comment: owww. $y^{2n} = (-1)^{n}b^{n}y$ and $y^{2n+1} = (-1)^{n}b^{n}y'$

Comment: so all derivatives will depend on y and y'. Very nice